# get Portal SMPT email user in portlet

Tags: email, liferay

I have a portlet that need to send a email to a list of user after his completion, and I want to use the email configured on 
"Control Panel > Server Administration > Email" to send then, but I can't get him

I tried using:

```
PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL_SMTP_USER)
```

but, without sucess

any tips?

sorry for my english....

EDIT:

I send my email with:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.setBody(bodyFromPreferences);
mailMessage.setSubject(subjectFromPreferences);
mailMessage.setFrom(from);
mailMessage.setTo(to);
MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting the username, password and other smtp data, you could also just use Liferay's [MailService](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/mail/service/MailService.html) to send your mail. Why bother dealing with data that should stay secret anyways when there's a service that knows how to deliver your mail.

As of the "From" address (as mentioned in the comment): Look through the various `FROM` options you find in [PropsKeys](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/PropsKeys.java) - I believe you've picked the login for the mail server with the property you're using in your question

Edit (answering your comment):

A standard MVC portlet with this view.jsp shows the sender name and address, no matter if they're configured through portal-ext.properties or through Control Panel (Portal Settings / EMail Notifications / Sender)

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsKeys"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PrefsPropsUtil"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<%
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
long companyId = themeDisplay.getCompanyId();
String fromName = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_FROM_NAME);
String fromAddress = PrefsPropsUtil.getString(companyId, PropsKeys.ADMIN_EMAIL_FROM_ADDRESS);
%>

From Name: <%=fromName%><br />
From Address: <%=fromAddress%><br />
```

Comment: I'am already using MailService, but I need the "from" don't?, or I'm doing somenthing wrong?

Comment: sorry, I missed that. Edited the answer

Comment: I tried with PropsKeys, but, that way only work's if I have configured my email through portal-ext.properties, other way he return de default's value from portal, since the configuration in "Control Panel > Server Administration > Email" are saved on my database....and thank's for the help : D

Comment: With that I can get the admin email, but he is different from the smpt email I configured

Comment: you mean the login user name for the SMTP server? That's what you should use the MailService for, so that you don't need it. Assume that this is not a valid email address but part of the login credentials.

Comment: I have find a solution

Comment: but with MailService, without a valid email he will return a exception , didn't? or you say to use the email I get from PrefsPropsUtil?

Comment: You'll construct a valid `com.liferay.portal.kernel.mail.MailMessage` (which takes the to and from address, and shouldn't take the account address for your admin email account - rather something that's explicitly configured as a FROM address. And then pass that into the `Mailservice`.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully retrieved the smtp Email, using this:

```
PortletPreferences serverPortletPreferences = PrefsPropsUtil
                .getPreferences();

        Map<String, String[]> serverPortletPreferencesMap = serverPortletPreferences
                .getMap();

        String emailUser = serverPortletPreferencesMap
                .get(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL_POP3_USER)[0];

        String emailAddress = serverPortletPreferencesMap
                .get(PropsKeys.MAIL_SESSION_MAIL_SMTP_USER)[0];
```

serverPortletPreferencesMap is map that have the keys in PropsKeys, so you can retrieve they if they are on portal.properties or in your DataBase